# My app's RouterModule isn't lazy loading posts

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink, angular-lazyloading

I am learning Angular and as a practice project, I am developing a front-end interface (with angular 13) for a Wordpress API served from a Docker container.

The angular app has to display the list of all posts obtained from the API and by making use of routing, once clicked on a post, in /post/:id:/:slug/ should be shown only the post requested.

My project's code: https://www.temporary-url.com/3BD84

My latest changes/commits, to implement lazy loading: https://www.temporary-url.com/08C

App looks like this:

[image: Home page of the app]

and these are some logs of what is being called:

[image: Home page logs]

When a post is clicked (for example the one titled Hello World), the url in the address bar changes correctly to host:port/post/1/hello-world and the following is called:

[image: Post click logs]

- but the page's content doesn't change. The clicked post isn't displayed (singularly). I suppose there is some routing issue, but haven't been able to find it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Router try to match the routes in the same order they are defined. Since you've defined the wildcard route `**` before the post page.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  {
    path: '**',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'post/:id/:slug',
    loadChildren: () => import('./post/post.module').then(m => m.PostModule),
  },
];
```

When you try to access a post url, the router is matching it to the wildcard route and creating a new `HomeComponent`

To solve it you just need to move the wildcard route to the end of the array.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you a lot, it solved the problem. It was easier than I thought :)